# Send data to API: jQuery Ajax POST with Contact Form 7 returns 500 error

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am trying to send my Wordpress Contact form 7 form data to an API after the form has been submitted with Ajax. The code is as follows:

```
$('body').on('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {
        if (event.detail.contactFormId == '1233') {
            var $form = $('.wpcf7-form');

            var formData = new FormData($form[0]);
            formData.append('submittingForm', '1');
            formData.append('submittingAjax', '1');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location.href,
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                async: true,
              success: function(data) {
                console.log('success',data);
              },
              error: function(data) {
                console.log('error',data);
              },
            }).done(function () {
               
            });
        }
});
```

Then trying to catch this in my Wordpress functions.php file to run a function if we have the data and run a cURL after that:

```
if (isset($_POST['submittingForm'])) {
   $this->contactFormTest();
}
```

For some reason my Ajax call results in an Internal 500 error (on localhost). Anything to suggest I'm doing wrong here or how to debug this? Is this the correct way to catch the form data here because I suspect its something regarding that but not sure how to do this elseway.

Comment: to note: I see the payload fine and data seems to be in the correct fields, although its Internal Error 500. When I use   contentType: "application/json", its 200 OK but the data is the site HTML not the correct payload

Comment: `how to debug this`...turn on php error reporting so you get a more useful error message